# Notification is not received but looks like sending is successful using Firebase and Retrofit2 in Android

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, retrofit2

I am working on notification but after A is sending notification B cannot receive the notification. I have added Toast to check and I can see sending was successful but it looks like onMessageReceived is not called. Could you please help where I make mistake? Thank you!!

Manifest

```
 <service android:name=".notifications.FirebaseService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_SERVICE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".notifications.FirebaseMessaging"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

This is onMessageReceived(). I could not see "message received"

```
    public class FirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
            //get current user from share preference
            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("SP_USER", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String savedCurrentUser = sp.getString("Current_USER", "None");

            Toast.makeText(this, "message received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String sent = remoteMessage.getData().get("sent");
            String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
            FirebaseUser fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if(fUser != null && sent.equals(fUser.getUid())) {
                if(!savedCurrentUser.equals(user)){
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
                       sendOAndAboveNotification(remoteMessage); 
                    }else {
                        sendNormalNotification(remoteMessage);
                    }
                }
            }


        }
```

This is where I send notification and I can see "Response" message

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Token token = ds.getValue(Token.class);
                    Data data = new Data(uid,name+":"+message,"New Message",destinationUid,R.drawable.icon_byb_final7);

                    Sender sender = new Sender(data, token.getToken());
                    apiService.sendNotification(sender)
                            .enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, retrofit2.Response<Response> response) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this,"Response"+response.message(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {

                                }
                            });
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like code is correct and it didn't work if I use both emulator phones. If you see the same issue you can try to install app in your mobile and try one from emulator. It works for me.